# Django ORM - AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to test Django REST API using unit test. Here is code of test case:

```
def test_orders_valid_data(self):
    try:
        o1 = md.ECare_Order.objects.create(order_id='aaaaa', created='2015-07-22',grand_total=120)
        o2 = md.ECare_Order.objects.create(order_id='aaaaa', created='2015-07-10', grand_total=100)

        o3 = md.ECare_Order.objects.create(order_id='bbbbb', created='2015-06-22', grand_total=90)
        orders = [o1,o2,o3]
        om1 = md.ECare_OrderMetric.objects.create(value=1,name='impression_order',order=o1)
        om2 = md.ECare_OrderMetric.objects.create(value=1,name='impression_order',order=o2)
        om3 = md.ECare_OrderMetric.objects.create(value=1,name='impression_order',order=o1)
        om4 = md.ECare_OrderMetric.objects.create(value=1,name='impression_order',order=o3)
        order_metrics = [om1,om2,om3,om4]

        for o in orders:
            o.save()
        for o in order_metrics:
            o.save()

        r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/analytics/v1/carters/engagement/order?window_days=30&end_date=08-08-2015")
        self.assertTrue(json.loads(r.text)['order_emails'],2)

finally:

    for o in orders:
        o.delete()
    for o in order_metrics:
        o.delete()
```

Problem is that when `o.delete()` in `finally` block is executed it raises the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
  File "/home/roman/dev/python/awo100/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 168, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/roman/dev/python/awo100/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

All other actions like `create` and `save` work fine and create and save object. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by adding

```
import django
django.setup()
```